# filter .click() objects by id or class names

Tags: javascript

How can I filter e object from a click action?
I want to prevent Firefox href propagation over checkboxes but I have other input on my html and the way implementes as is, will prevent my inputs to submit:

```
<a href="picture-big.jpg">
      <img src="https://imgur.com/gallery/DC0Iu" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="delete" id="stopprop1"/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="delete" id="stopprop"/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="delete" class="stopprop"/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="delete" class="stopprop"/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="delete" class="stopprop"/>
</a>
```

JS:

```
$('input').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var _this = this;
      console.log(_this.getElementById('stopprop'))
      setTimeout(function() { 
        _this.checked = !_this.checked; 
      }, 1);
});
```

Can I filter e object? and if e has class or id x then prevent that from href propagation.

Some other input buttons on the same page which is prevented to submit.

```
<div class="cell empty" data-title="">
<input type="submit" class="recover-css" name="recover_vms" value="RECOVER" />
</div>
```

Comment: First, your HTML is invalid. You cannot include interactive content within the anchor. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element. Also, the name attribute in your grouped checkboxes should be followed by `[]` in order for them to be grouped.

Comment: var _this = document

Comment: Pretty sure that `[]` in name attributes is only relevant to PHP?

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` tag cannot have `input` inside of it. But for your quesion:

You can get the `class` or `id` of the clicked element with jQuery by using `$(e.target).attr('id')` for `id` and `$(e.target).attr('class')` for `class`

So your code may look like this:

```
    $('input').click(function(e) {
      if ($(e.target).attr('id') === 'someid') {
        //do something
      }
      if ($(e.target).attr('class') === 'someclass') {
        //do something else
      }
    });
```